# Отображение нескольких Imagebutton на разных экранах

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте! Вопрос заключается в следующем: что необходимо сделать, чтобы несколько imagebutton (допустим пять), расположенных на одном Relativelayout, отображались одинаково на устройствах с разными диагоналями экранов, т.е чтобы все пять кнопок были полностью видны и не обрезались как на большом экране, так и на экране меньших размеров. Спасибо.

Comment: Вам, думаю, надо через вес размеры проставить. Так будет пропорционально экрану любому. А вообще - вопрос слишком расплывчатый, сложно ответить.

Comment: "Вам, думаю, надо через вес размеры проставить"- можно поподробнее?

Comment: А можно ли вручную для каждой диагонали экрана сделать чтобы imagebutton отображались так как мне нужно, т.е. чтобы не "наползали " друг на друга и смотрелись одинаково и пропорционально размеру любого экрана?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте вес - он позволяет задать один из параметров пропорционально от контейнера.

Эта разметка задаст каждой View одинаковую высоту в пределах контейнера, т.е. 1/4 экрана

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```